# Security-related question regarding private key in repo for localhost

Tags: security, ssl, ssh, mbedtls

Secure sockets use a CN check against certs in a trust collection with the domain accepting or connecting.  For myself I created a private and public set for localhost and that helps me debug locally. If I wanted to offer an SDK, would it be considered secure to distribute a .key and .cer X509 for this localhost debugging use-case?  Or is it always not considered secure to have a .key in any open space at all, because of its potential misuse?

Sorry if this is discussed in other places but I cannot find out a clear answer on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be somewhat opinionated and also depends on your project somewhat, but I think the main risk is how people will actually use those. Some of them will use it for production for sure, because it is easier, or they don't understand keypairs and just want it to work and so on.

Any project should be secure by default, for everybody involved, including endusers and developers as well if your project is something like a library or component. Secure by default in this case would mean not providing an actual keypair, because that would potentially be a backdoor in case of at least some of its uses - even though it was not meant to be used like that.

Another thing to consider is the reputation of your project. If you include a key and users misuse it on the internet, it will be easy to find and potentially exploit vulnerable instances of your project with tools like Shodan. Nobody will care the developers did it wrong - it will be your project that's found vulnerable.

A better way to consider would be to provide something like an init script that would generate a key and a certificate for that specific instance. It could still be easy for the user and developer, and also secure for everybody. In case of a linux package, this could even be done by the installer script with most packaging solutions so it would be fully transparent for the user.

Comment: Thank you for your advice on the subject.  Well taken, and I do believe it may be prudent to have a config panel with generation of the key pairs.